# A contest on multiple platforms with monetary reward

Tags: discussion, meta

*(this question relates to [that "real TV" attempt at KOTH challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155973/real-tv-contest))*

I'd like to submit a game with the following characteristics, and I'd like to discuss whether or not it is acceptable here, and to what conditions:

- game will be self-contained, but simultaneously posted on at least another platform
- that other platform will give crypto-currency reward to the winners, but only if
- game will have an unambiguous scoreboard for prize determination

Note 1: money is provided (in very short) by the platform "likes", people liking (as in facebook) the post contribute to the prize pool

Note 2: Following advice on OP comments, I went through [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-we-allowed-to-offer-real-world-prizes-such-as-gift-codes-to-the-winner-of-a/1895#1895). My understanding is that monetary prize is unusual but not strictly forbidden

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/whats-the-ppcg-policy-on-originality-of-content).

Comment: Note that this discourages competition (after the money had been offered, relatively)

Comment: Would answers here also compete with answers on the other site? Since submissions here are posted publicly, that could be them at a disadvantage.

Comment: @xnor: all answers must be public. Posted here or there and merged to a public git project so anyone can compete in a fair way

Answer (score 8):

Though (AFAIK) it's technically not forbidden by SE, it's not a great idea to offer monetary rewards for content posted to SE. If you really want to do this, you should only mention that the challenge is also hosted somewhere else. I would forgo any mention of the possibility of monetary reward from that other platform, and make it very clear that the challenge on PPCG is independent of the challenge on the other platform.

What other platforms do or do not do is not our concern, so if you can maintain an arm's-length separation between PPCG and the other platform, you should be alright.